# Connecting to a rest API with python. How to setup headers & parameters?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

i'm working on settin up a rest api with python, however i'm having some problem getting it to work.

I'm working with the TV DB rest api: https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger

and using python with Requests library to pull out the information.

My code is currently:

```
import json 
import requests

 URL = "https://api.thetvdb.com/"

API_KEY = "Api_key"
USER_KEY = "Key"
USERNAME = "Name"

headers  = {"Accept": "application/json"}
params = {
  "apikey": API_KEY,
  "userkey": USER_KEY,
  "username": USERNAME
}

resp = requests.post(URL + "login/", headers = headers ,params=params)

if resp.status_code != 200:
    print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
else:
    print('Success')
```

So far i'm only getting error code 401, not sure why.

**Solved:**

2 Things needed to be changed
1. The resp was changed into:

```
resp = requests.post(URL + "login/", headers = headers, data=json.dumps(params))
```

2. The header had to have

   ```
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
   ```

added to it :) It's now working, thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login parameters probably need to be a JSON-encoded string POSTed as the body of the message.

Try `resp = requests.post(URL + "login/", headers = headers, data=json.dumps(params))`

Comment: also you can use `resp.raise_for_status()` instead of the if/else block to make for cleaner code.

Comment: You can also use the `requests.post(..., json=params)` to have `requests` do the JSON encoding for your.

Comment: This seems to have done something different, however, I am now getting error 415, not sure why

Comment: Fixed it! 

Error 415 was fixed by adding: Content-Type: application/json into header

Comment: You probably also need the header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Yup got it! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I am trying the above solution to login to bugzilla api to get bugs. I get error code 404. I am just using my API key and username. Any suggestions on that.